# pandas import erroR in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to import pandas using

```
>>>import pandas as pd
```

but I am getting following error. I have un installed and installed pandas many times to resolve this problem but it seems to be not helping.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "pandas.py", line 3, in <module>
print('Pandas version ' + pd.__version__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: try to import the module in cmd, are you able to import it ? also try changing the file name from `pandas.py` to `something.py`

Comment: i am using ubuntu.In terminal and spyder  both has same problem while importing.

Comment: Did you try renaming your script as stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the file name named pandas.py which was a empty file in python path. I have no idea why it was present. When I deleted it. This worked fine.

Comment: Or you may have created the file.